Python Requests Authentication Issue: Setting cookies?
I am trying to scrape a Hertz Rental Car API (URL below) to get pricing options for a specific itinerary. This is not on the disallow list on their robots.txt. I captured the payload from my browser stemming from the initial Hertz (Hertz.com) page populating the trip details (location, dates, pickup times) that is submitted to the request URL below. When I then hit the API below with my payload, headers (token and user agent), cookies, and URL (copied from my network tab), I get a 200 response, but never get my anticipated response as I would expect to see based on what I see in my browser network tab when performing in my browser. I tried making my headers just my token and not having cookies, but that gave me an Incapsula issue. I believe this is a cookie issue based on the response below, and I think my method of taking my Hertz.com response to set my cookie is not working. Need guidance/help.
Request URL: "https://www.hertz.com/rentacar/rest/hertz/v2/itinerary/vehicles"
Code:
import requests
import time

#URL 1 utilized to hit Hertz page and ideally return cookies to do API query with URL 2
url1="https://www.hertz.com"

url2="https://www.hertz.com/rentacar/rest/hertz/v2/itinerary/vehicles"

headers={"dtm_token":"HereIsAfakeTokenforAnExample",
          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

#Payload copied from browser when performing the request from Hertz's homepage with trip details (location, dates, times)
#This payload is what is submitted by your browser when making a request to book a rental via URL2
params={'lastName': '', 'resSearch': False, 'showRentalAgreement': False, 'showEvRentalAgreement': False, 'goldAnytimeRes': False,
        'checkLIS': False, 'checkFPO': False, 'buttonLIS': False, 'buttonFPO': False, 'showBothElements': False,
        'cdpVerificationFailed': 0, 'forceResHomePage': '', 'href': '/rentacar/rest/home/form', 'confirmationNumber': '',
        'arrivingUpdate': '', 'defaultTab': '', 'militaryClock': 0, 'majorAirport': '', 'returnAtDifferentLocationCheckbox': '',
        'dropoffLocation': '', 'inpPickupAutoFill': 'Y', 'inpPickupStateCode': 'VA', 'inpPickupCountryCode': '', 'inpPickupSearchType': '3',
        'inpDropoffAutoFill': '', 'inpDropoffStateCode': '', 'inpDropoffCountryCode': '', 'inpDropoffSearchType': '', 'pickupHiddenEOAG': 'IADT26',
        'dropoffHiddenEOAG': '', 'memberOtherCdpField': '', 'cdpField': '', 'corporateRate': '', 'officialTravel': '',
        'pcNumber': '', 'typeInRateQuote': 'BEST', 'cvNumber': '', 'itNumber': '', 'originalRqCheckBox': '', 'checkDiscount': '',
        'affiliateMemberJoin': '', 'affiliateMemberID': '', 'affiliateCallCount': 0, 'hertzlinkActive': False, 'companyId': '',
        'pickupDay': '05/22/2024', 'pickupTime': '12:00', 'dropoffDay': '05/23/2024', 'dropoffTime': '12:00', 'no1ClubNumber': '',
        'selectedCarType': 'ACAR', 'ageSelector': '25', 'redeemPoints': '', 'fromLocationSearch': False,
        'recommendationBrowserInfo': {'appCodeName': 'Mozilla', 'appName': 'Netscape', 'appVersion':
                                      '5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
                                      'cookieEnabled': True, 'language': 'en-US', 'onLine': True, 'platform': 'MacIntel', 'product': 'Gecko',
                                      'userAgent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36', 'visitorId': ''},
        'pickupLocation': 'Washington Dulles International Airport', 'inpPickupIsServedBy': 'N', 'inpPickupHasSpecialInstruction': 'N',
        'pickupDayStandard': '2024/05/22', 'dropoffDayStandard': '2024/05/23', 'inpPickupOptGoldAnytime': '', 'memberSelectedCdp': '', 'cdpRadioButton': ''}

response1=requests.get(url1, headers=headers)

#introducing sleep to make this less machine-like
time.sleep(2)

#used for debugging
print(response1.status_code)
print(response1.cookies)

#API request to get rental options and pricing
response2=requests.get(url2, headers=headers, params=params, cookies=response1.cookies)

#used for debugging
print(response2.status_code)
print(response2.text)
print(response2.cookies)

Terminal Results:
200
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
200
See response below for snippet of 85-line response
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
Response:
As you were browsing something about your browser made us think you were a bot. There are a few reasons this might happen:

You've disabled JavaScript in your web browser.
You're a power user moving through this website with super-human speed.
You've disabled cookies in your web browser.
A third-party browser plugin, such as Ghostery or NoScript, is preventing JavaScript from running. Additional information is available in this support article.

To regain access, please make sure that cookies and JavaScript are enabled before reloading the page.
You'll need a managed/embedded browser to perform javascript actions on a webapp. Pure http actions via requests can't do it alone. Look into selenium, its the most used for automating browser actions using python.

I believe( from similar experience) that Hertz may be running some javascript in the background to verify or regenerate cookies, if you can re-implement this functionality in python, you might be able to do it without a managed browser. Go into the Network tab of your browser's dev tools, it shows you approximately which javascript/html code generated a http request

Is it possible that I could retrieve cookies via hitting Hertz.com and use them for the vehicles API? I assumed I was not retrieving the cookies correctly given my "<RequestsCookieJar[]>" and just fixing that would do the trick.

With respect to the Network tab of the browser, are you suggesting to filter for JS only requests and try to figure out which one generated the api request to /vehicles? (don't know JS).

from the error message you entered right there, the problem is most likely javascript not loading copying cookies might help, you can google how to do it, I haven't done that in a while. As for network requests, you want to look at all requests and see which requests have similar parameters to the one you're trying to send. Then you can go ahead and replicate that.

2 ways to replicate, you can click "Initiator" and see what initiated the request, OR you can also right click "copy as curl", then you can then go to curlconverter.com, which will convert the curl command to valid python for you
